# Efficiently break html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this simple markup:

```
<p> some content here </p>
```

I want to break it into

```
<p> some </p> content <p> here </p>
```

using javascript (or with jQuery help).
I want to break html `p` tag, so that my particular word (for example `content`) will be out of the `p`. I want to find cross browser and efficient solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the word you want to break on always known? Or do you break on, say, the middle word in the sentence always?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? It seems like they're might be a better solution. That sentence belongs in a **paragraph** tag.

Comment: it can be any tag, I selected `p` by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function () {
  $.fn.extend({
    splitAt: function (splitter) {
      this.each(function () {
        var $replacement = $(), $org = $(this);

        $.each($org.text().split(splitter), function (_, val) {
          $replacement = $replacement.add($org.clone().html(val)).add(document.createTextNode(splitter));
        });

        $org.replaceWith($replacement.slice(0, -1));
      });

      return $(this.selector, this.context);
    }
  });
}(jQuery));

$('p').splitAt('content').css('background', 'lightblue');
​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hSQ2m/6/

Answer (score 1):

try this.. just change the selectors and the word to be picked and excluded from the selector

```
$('p').text($('p').text().replace('content','</p>content<p>'));
```

Comment: $('p').html($('p').html().replace('content','</p> content <p>'));

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Text.splitText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Text.splitText) and the example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('p').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('content','</p>content<p>'));​
})
```

using each to loop the selected text sets the HTML of the `p` element by getting its HTML and replacing `content` with `</p>content<p>`

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ns5PG/1/)

**Update**

thanks to @Yoshi's comments below ... a better way without the each() loop :

```
$('p').html(function (_, html) {
  return html.replace('content','</p>content<p>');
});​
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/hSQ2m/)

Comment: You could use the `html` function like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hSQ2m/ to avoid the duplicate selector evaluation.

Comment: @Yoshi nice ... can you please explain the `_` to me ?

Comment: jQuery will pass the index of the element as the first parameter, me using `_` as it's name is just to show that I don't actually need it. Using the `html` like show, also removes the need to cycle over the elements (thus no `each` needed).

Comment: @Yoshi :-) thanks for the explanation ! i did confuse me for a second !! updated my answer with your suggestion

Comment: Both of you are hardcoding "content" and that's no efficient as title of this post said :-)

Comment: @OscarJara deriving a parameterized solution from a functional *hard-coded* solution is probably the easiest part of this whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I made this for you:

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/A4efg/1/

**this will work with any text you want** inside your `<p></p>` tags.

HTML:

```
<p> some content here </p>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Do it!"/>
<br/><br/>
results will be here:
<div id="result"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){

    // clean the "result" div each time you invoke "click"
    $('#result').html('');

    // get the text inside "<p></p>" tags
    var str = $('p').html();

    // make an array for all elements inside tag
    // result: ["", "some", "content", "here", ""]
    var substr = str.split(' ');

    // remove "space" elements from the array
    // result: ["some", "content", "here"]
    removeFromArray(substr, '');

    // populate the "result" div where i = index, e = element
    // result:
    //   some
    //   content
    //   here
    $.each(substr, function(i, e){
         $('#result').append('<p> ' + substr[i] + ' </p>');
    });
});

/* Function to remove element from js array */
function removeFromArray(arr){
    var what, a= arguments, L= a.length, ax;
    while(L> 1 && arr.length){
        what= a[--L];
        while((ax= arr.indexOf(what))!= -1){
            arr.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

CSS - just to style :-)

```
div#result{
   color: red; 
}​
```

Hope this helps :-)
​